# ¿Como reresar el resultado de un query en SQlite 3 como un arreglo en Swift?

Tags: sql, swift, sqlite

Tengo una consulta que me regresa los registros de una tabla, la cual accedo a estos datos desde otra funcion.

```
func getCoords() -> ([Int],[String],[Double],[Double],[Int]) {

    let queryStatementString = "SELECT * FROM coords;"

    var queryStatement: OpaquePointer?
      if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,queryStatementString,-1,&queryStatement,nil) == SQLITE_OK {
        while (sqlite3_step(queryStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
           idRow = Int(sqlite3_column_int(queryStatement, 0))
           hour1 = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(queryStatement, 1))
           getLat = sqlite3_column_double(queryStatement, 2)
           getLon = sqlite3_column_double(queryStatement, 3)
           conCorrds = Int(sqlite3_column_int(queryStatement, 4))
            
            idArray += [idRow]
            hourArray += [hour1]
            latArray += [getLat]
            lonArray += [getLon]
            conArray += [conCorrds]
          //print("Query Result COORDS:")
          //print("|\(hour1!) | \(getLat!) | \(getLon!) |\(conCorrds!)")
            //idArray += [id]
        }
        
      } else {
          let errorMessage = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db))
          print("\nQuery is not prepared \(errorMessage)")
      }
      sqlite3_finalize(queryStatement)
     
   return (idArray,hourArray,latArray,lonArray,conArray)
}
```

pero nesecito retorar un solo arreglo con sus elementos, un ejemplo seria:

```
[(idRow: 1,hourArray:09:00:00,latArray:12.12456,lonArray:21.123456,conCoords:1),
(idRow: 2,hourArray:09:10:00,latArray:12.12656,lonArray:21.92121,conCoords:3)]
```

Y en mi otra funcion poder utlizar ese arreglo

```
let coordsInfo = getCoords()

let idForCoords = coordsInfo["idRow"]
```

etc...

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear una estructura:

```
struct MiStruct {
    var idRow: Int
    var hour1: String
    var getLat: Double
    var getLon: Double
    var conCorrds: Int

    init(idRow: Int, hour1: String, getLat: Double, getLon: Double, conCorrds: Int) {
        self.idRow = idRow
        self.hour1 = hour1
        self.getLat = getLat
        self.getLon = getLon
        self.conCorrds = conCorrds
    }
}
```

En la función retornas un array de ese tipo de objeto en donde almacenas toda la data del Query:

```
func getCoords() -> [MiStruct] {
    var resultado = [MiStruct]()//Inicializas una variable del tipo de la estructura
    let queryStatementString = "SELECT * FROM coords;"

    var queryStatement: OpaquePointer?
      if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,queryStatementString,-1,&queryStatement,nil) == SQLITE_OK {
        while (sqlite3_step(queryStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
           idRow = Int(sqlite3_column_int(queryStatement, 0))
           hour1 = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(queryStatement, 1))
           getLat = sqlite3_column_double(queryStatement, 2)
           getLon = sqlite3_column_double(queryStatement, 3)
           conCorrds = Int(sqlite3_column_int(queryStatement, 4))
            
            //Agregas los datos al array
            resultado.append(MiStruct(idRow: idRow, hour1: hour1, getLat: getLat, getLon: getLon, conCorrds: conCorrds))
        }
        
      } else {
          let errorMessage = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db))
          print("\nQuery is not prepared \(errorMessage)")
      }
      sqlite3_finalize(queryStatement)
   //Retornas el resultado  
   return resultado
}
```

Para obtener los datos recorres el array:

```
let coordsInfo = getCoords()

if coordsInfo.count > 0 {
    for data in coordsInfo {
        print(data.idRow)
        print(data.conCorrds)
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias era lo que nesecitaba :)